# How to convert dictionary to strings?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

my_dict:

```
{0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}
```

using this to grab name in dicts :

```
 for ids in [v['name'] for v in my_dict.values()]:
 #subprocess.call(["...", name])
 print(ids)
```

Now I'm doing this to generate jsons with values generated in ids

faker library is used here to create random data

```
import faker
import json
import subprocess


for ids in [g['name'] for g in my_dict.values()]:

    fake = Faker('en_US')
    print(ids)
    for ind in ids:

        for idx in range(1):

                sms =  {
                    "user_id": ind ,
                    "name": fake.name(),
                    "email": fake.email(),
                    "gender": "MALE",
                    "mother_name": fake.name(),
                    "father_name": fake.name()
                    }

        f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
        print(f_name)
        with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(sms, fp, indent=4)
```

output i need:  elpato.json , petoka.json.

output i'm getting:

```
  e.json
  l.json
  p.json
  a.json
  t.json
  o.json

  p.json
  e.json
  t.json
  o.json
  k.json
  a.json
```

Comment: What is `Faker`? Please add that definition as well, also I don't see `userId` key in `my_dict`

Comment: updated @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see  userId key in my_dict, also clarify what you want in the file name as well, instead of just providing the names

Comment: you would rather need `ind = ids` instead of `for ind in ids:`

Comment: @furas it worked but if i has to print 10 it is printing 8 only. when i print my_dict and f_name it is showing 10 files but in local pc only 8 jsons are there couldn't figure out

Comment: do you have 10 items with 10 different names ? If you have some name two times in dictionary then you get one json file instead of two files.

Comment: no when i tried printing f_name to check whether there are only 8 . it is printing 10 json file names. when i write them to pc. 2 are missing  `f_name = '{}.json'.format(ind)
        print(f_name)
        with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(sms, fp, indent=4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> my_dict = {0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}
>>> ", ".join('{}.json'.format(v) for ik,iv in d.items() for k,v in iv.items() if k == 'name')
'elpato.json, petoka.json' # output in string form
```

Replace with (complete code),

```
import faker
import json
import subprocess

my_dict = {0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}

f_names = [(ik, '{}.json'.format(v)) for ik,iv in my_dict.items() for k,v in iv.items() if k == 'name']
for values in f_names:
    fake = Faker('en_US')
    ind,f_name = [*values]
    sms =  {
            "user_id": ind ,
            "name": fake.name(),
            "email": fake.email(),
            "gender": "MALE",
            "mother_name": fake.name(),
            "father_name": fake.name()
            }
    with open(f_name, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(sms, fp, indent=4)
```

Comment: one line solution grt

Comment: in which part i should use this line

Comment: like this :  `for ids in [g['userId'] for g in my_dict " ".join('{}.json'.format(v) for ik,iv in d.items() for k,v in iv.items() if k == 'name')]:`

Comment: @elmantospetus NO, you no need to use for-loop. Once, you `my_dict` contains data. Replace your complete `for-loop` and add my code.

Comment: only one for-loop i should remove or all. cz im getting ids not defined  `for ind in ids:`

Comment: @elmantospetus Answer was updated. Check and accept the answer, if it solved your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195608/discussion-between-elmanto-spetus-and-shaik-moeed).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {0: {'Id': 'd1', 'name': 'elpato', 'email': '122as@gmail.com'}, 1: {'Id': 'd2', 'name': 'petoka', 'email': 'sss@gmail.com'}}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print(my_dict[k]['name']+".json")
```

Alternatively, try below code in place of `print(my_dict[k]['name']+".json")`:

```
print('{}.json'.format(my_dict[k]['name']))
```

You can also try this:

```
for value in my_dict.values():
    print('{}.json'.format(value['name']))
```

output:

```
elpato.json
petoka.json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [14]: ', '.join(f"{i['name']}.json" for i in my_dict.values())
Out[14]: 'elpato.json, petoka.json'
```

another option is to use:

```
You can use print(f"{f_name}.josn", end = ', ')
```

Comment: why you have posted two answers?